# A paste event triggered manually has no .originalEvent property?

Tags: jquery

When I trigger a paste event with .trigger(), the ensuing captured paste event has no .originalEvent property. Is this expected behavior? Why?

See example - http://jsfiddle.net/2uxEr/

```
<textarea>Paste something here</textarea>
<button>Click for fake trigger</button>

$('textarea').on("paste", function(e){

     alert(e.hasOwnProperty("originalEvent"));

});

$('button').click(function(){

    $('textarea').trigger("paste");

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery events will not have an `originalEvent` property if they were triggered manually. How could they? The `originalEvent` is the event object created by the browser from which jQuery formed its event object; in a manually triggered event, jQuery created the event object itself. There is no `originalEvent` to access.

[This jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2uxEr/1/) shows how this is true for events like `click` as well as `paste`.

Comment: jQuery doesn't trigger the native event? How does it work then?

Comment: @HyShai It [adds an event listener](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L104) so the browser's native event is caught. jQuery then enhances this object to add features and usability and passes it on to your code.

Comment: I mean the .trigger() method. How does it trigger the event? The event thats triggered is recognized by vanilla JS also.

Comment: @HyShai jQuery builds a `jQuery.Event` object from scratch, and then gives that to you. It then [deliberately fires this event](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L297) on all the relevant elements up the tree.